# SQL Выборка записей отсортированных с учётом бонусов

Tags: sql, сортировка

Есть таблица очередей clan_help_parts с полями id, date, login, bonus, penalty.

Задача: вывести записи таблицей, упорядоченных по дате, при этом сдвигать записи с учётом бонусов-пенальти.

Если без сортировки по дате, то работает так:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, (id + penalty - bonus) as position FROM clan_help_parts ORDER BY position";
```

Т.е. нужно, чтобы они сначала сортировались по дате, а потом к ним применялись сдвиги (т.е. например bonus = 1 означает что позиция в очереди сдвинется на -1 к началу). Вариант "ORDER BY date, position" не то.

Можно ли это сделать в один запрос? Или вариант только выводить в php в многомерный массив, там назначать позиции-сдвиги, потом сортировать и выводить.

Comment: вычислить номер позиции по дате, т.е. отсортировать по дате и пронумеровать. потом обернуть во внешний запрос и там вычислить новые позиции. Логика же примерно такая ? А вот как именно это сделать зависит от используемой СУБД и ее версии (могут быть применены переменные MySQL или оконные функции для других СУБД или еще какие механизмы)

Comment: @Mike , да, логика такая. Вопрос в том, как именно это сделать (база MySQL), пусть и комбинированным запросом. Пример кода нужен...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *, num-bonus
  from (
    select *, @num:=@num+1 num
      from clan_help_parts, (select @num:=0) x
     order by date
  ) y
order by num-bonus
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, так работает! А можете прокомментировать строки 3,4? B num-bonus это переменная или арифметическая операция? Мне бы ещё чтобы penalty учитывалось...

Comment: @DarkWizard В стороке 4 переменной `@num` присваивается 0, что бы было с чего начинать нумерацию. В 3 строке эта переменная увеличивается на 1 на каждой новой строке и появляется поле с именем num которое собственно эту нумерацию содержит. Во внешнем запросе вычитаем из порядкового номера num бонус